# How to reset Raspberry Pi B+ to the default version?

Tags: raspberry-pi, reset

There is a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ which was already used.
I need to bring it to the default settings, i.e. to the state which you get it from the store (so that I can start using from scratch again, I want raspberry to forget all the previous actions, like it is new. Or simply cancel all the previous actions one has done).

What I did:
I tried to search "how to reset" or bring to the default, I could not find anything. Everything is about factory default and reinstalling some image.
Among useful commands I didn't find: https://raspberrytips.com/raspberry-pi-commands/

Isn't it not simple like resetting a smartphone? I may google differently.

Comment: If you remove the SD card is the system back in the state you got it from the store?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to reset my raspberry pi is to rewrite (reflash) an SD card of it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntaXWS8Lk34